# Give a example to show that $F$ is not necessarily a sub-bundle of $E$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

> Suppose $(E, B, \pi)$ is a vector bundle of dimension $n$, $\pi: E\rightarrow B$. If $F\subset E$ and for every $x\in B$, the fibre $F_x(:=\pi^{-1}(x)\cap F)$ is a linear subsbace of $E_x(:=\pi^{-1}(x))$, give a example to show that $F$ is not necessarily a sub-bundle of $E$.

> $F$ is a sub-bundle of $E$: for any set $U$ in the open covering of $B$, there is a trivialization $h_U:\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ such that (k is a fixed natural number)
> $$
> h_U(\pi^{-1}(U)\cap F)=U\times(\mathbb{R}^k\times\{0\}).
> $$

I am just learning some concept of vector bundle. I have no idea how to construct such an example, and another exercise in my textbook seems to imply such an example does not exsit when $B=\mathbb{R}$. Since we can alwars view a linear space of dimension $n$ as $\mathbb{R}^n$, the main point is to find appropriate $B$.

Appreciate any help or hint. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a really trivial way in which $F$ can fail to be a sub-bundle: the dimension of $F_x$ can vary (this is allowed by your problem).

Comment: ...but even if you assume that $F_x$ is always (say) of dimension $1$, it's also possible for the subspaces $F_x \subseteq E_x$ to vary in a discontinuous fashion, which would also mean that $F$ is not a sub-bundle. Take, for instance, the trivial two-dimensional bundle $\mathbf{R}^2$ on the base $B=\mathbf{R}$, and for $F_p$ take the subset which is the $y$-axis in $\mathbf{R}^2$ for all $p \neq 0$ and the $x$-axis for $p=0$.